# Expand a copy Range

Tags: excel

I have a button driven macro that copies a range of cells to the clipboard (so I can place in other documents):

```
 Sub Button2_Click()
 '
 ' Button2_Click Macro
  Range("A1:p43").Copy

 End Sub
```

Form time to time I need to either add or delete a row in that range in the worksheet. What I need is for the copy range to expand (or contract) to the number of rows containing the values. Note: the columns will not adjust, just the rows.

Comment: Any reason the macro only does one thing? Kind of overkill to just copy?

Answer (score 0):

If the copy range is a contiguous range of values with a blank column in column Q and a blank row below row 43, you can use the CurrentRegion property like this:

`Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy`

It's basically the same as clicking A1 and then using Ctrl-Shift-Down arrow and Ctrl-Shift-Right arrow.

Comment: This code only seemed to copy from cells A1 to P2 not all the way down to P43?

Comment: I explained the requirements: contiguous range. That means no blank rows or blank columns between A1 and P43. Excel cannot read your mind. It needs something to go by. You may want to post your data sample so we are all looking at the same thing. Update your question, then post a comment.